# SQL Server SubQuery Error - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to select multiple values from 3 subqueries and combine them together. But I get the error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Here is my code.

```
SELECT(
SELECT ROUND(
  (SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) FROM WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass=1 )
  /(SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) from WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass is not null)*100,0) AS [Quality],

(SELECT ROUND(
CAST((SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING') AS float)/
CAST(
((SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS IdleTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Idle Time')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS SetupTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='MACHINE SETUP')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS DownTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR 
INNER JOIN REASON_CODE RC ON RESOURCE_LABOR.ReasonCode = RC.ReasonCode WHERE  RC.ReasonType='3'))AS FLOAT)*100,0) AS [Availability]),

(SELECT ROUND((
((SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) AS TotalCount from WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass is not null)/
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING'))/
15)*100,0) AS [Performance]))
```

I don't see where I'm selecting multiple columns in my WHERE clause. Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in bracketing correctly. Its a complicated combination of subqueries and I didnt realize there was a missing bracket. Here is the code that works

```
SELECT
(SELECT ROUND(
  (SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) FROM WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass=1 )
  /(SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) from WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass is not null)*100,0)) AS Quality,

(SELECT ROUND(
CAST((SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING') AS float)/
CAST(
((SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS IdleTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Idle Time')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS SetupTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='MACHINE SETUP')+
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS DownTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR 
INNER JOIN REASON_CODE RC ON RESOURCE_LABOR.ReasonCode = RC.ReasonCode WHERE  RC.ReasonType='3'))AS FLOAT)*100,0))Availability,

(
SELECT ROUND((
((SELECT SUM(TotalProcessed) AS TotalCount from WIP_CONTENT WHERE WipContentClass is not null)/
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [StartTime], [EndTime])) AS UpTime FROM RESOURCE_LABOR WHERE  ReasonCode='Running' OR ReasonCode='RUNNING'))/
15)*100,0)) AS Performance
```